# Sql queries using distinct sum and subtract function

Tags: sql

I need from you to help me to extract a query from one table for financial transaction and its rows as follows : 
Accountnumber :for example (4568643)
Transactionamount :for example (1000 dollar)
Kindoftransaction (debit or credit )
transactionfile (and this number holds the file number that linked to this transaction)

I need your help to extract Query for the net balance of each (transactionfile) after sum All 
(Transactionamount) holds "credit" from (Kindoftransaction) and subtract it from sum of All (Transactionamount) holds "debit" where 
(Accountnumber) is (4568643)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select transactionfile, sum(case when kindoftransaction = 'debit' then -1 else 1 end * transactionamount)
from financial
where accountnumber = 4568643
group by transactionfile
```

Comment: Dear please note that the result is ok ..., but i missing to show the (transactionfile)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? - note it helps if you could post your table definition

```
DECLARE @transactions TABLE
(
    [AccountNumber] INT NOT NULL,
    [TransactionAmount] DECIMAL(18, 10) NOT NULL,
    [KindOfTransaction] CHAR(1) NOT NULL, -- this could be better served as a boolean / bit field
    [TransactionFile] INT NOT NULL
)

-- dummy data
INSERT INTO @transactions VALUES(4568643, 100, 'C', 123)
INSERT INTO @transactions VALUES(4568643, 150, 'C', 124)
INSERT INTO @transactions VALUES(4568643, 50, 'D', 125)
INSERT INTO @transactions VALUES(2345623, 100, 'C', 126)
INSERT INTO @transactions VALUES(2345623, 79, 'C', 127)

    -- here's the actual query to return your data using a common table expression
;WITH cteAccountSummary (AccountNumber, TotalCredits, TotalDebits) AS (
    SELECT  [AccountNumber], 
            SUM(
                CASE [KindOfTransaction]
                    WHEN 'C' THEN [TransactionAmount]
                    ELSE 0
                END
            ),
            SUM(
                CASE [KindOfTransaction]
                    WHEN 'D' THEN [TransactionAmount]
                    ELSE 0
                END
            )
    FROM @transactions
    GROUP BY [AccountNumber]
)
SELECT [AccountNumber], TotalCredits - TotalDebits AS 'NetFinancialPosition'
FROM cteAccountSummary
```

Comment: 1st i have to thank you for your answer but if you can please re-type the query in one line as it shown

Comment: I can not have any results could you please specify again the query ... Thanks